# Nodejs - No webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, build

I want to "bundle" some files into a **single js** file, but **I don't want** the webpack wrapper.

---

Let's say I have 3 files :

```
// file1.js
export default { hello: "hello" };

// file2.js
export default { world: "world" };

// index.js
import file1 from "./file1";
import file2 from "./file2";

(() => ({ ...file1, ...file2 }))()
```

---

I want the following result :

```
// build/output.js (+ babel...)
(function(){
  return Object.assign({}, { hello: "hello" }, { world: "world" });
})()
```

Not a single line of code apart from the above build output.

---

Is it possible with webpack? Thanks!

Comment: you can't "not have the webpack wrapper". If you don't want that, webpack is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so... But If there is a simple solution that uses Babel to transpile the code before it is "bundled", that will be awesome! Webpack isn't required here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## O.P. Solution

Ok, so I found a solution! 
It's maybe not the best one, but it works.

I found [this library here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundle-js) which concatenates files together.

---

## Building

I can build using : `npm run build`.

And the code that concatenates the files is :

```
// ======================================================
// Tools / Bundle
// ======================================================

// Libs
var path = require("path");
var bundle = require("bundle-js");

module.exports.exec = function() {
  // Disable logging (hack for 'bundle-js' library).
  var _log = console.log;
  console.log = function() {};

  // Concatenate each file (required by the application).
  var file = path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.js");
  var bundledCode = bundle({
    entry: file,
    print: false,
    disablebeautify: true
  });

  // Enable logging.
  console.log = _log;

  // Return bundled code.
  return bundledCode;
};
```

For some reasons, **bundle-js** always outputs something even with the option `{ print: false }`. So I added a small hack to fix this.